# Avoid row selection of JTable by click on definite column

Tags: java, jtable, selection

I want to click on a `JTable` row. Clicking on the first column of any row (`column.index=0`), will highlight the row. Clicking on any other column in a row should not highlight the row. How can i realize this, please?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

//Sry - problemes with editor-tool

public class JTableTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public JTableTest() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    getContentPane().add(jButton1, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"click will select", null},
            {"click will select", null},
            {"click will select", null},
            {"click will select", null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "String", "Boolean"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new JTableTest().setVisible(true);
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
```

}